# DjangoでMySQLにHTMLを入力（保存？）

Tags: html, mysql, python3, django

お忙しいところ大変申し訳無いのですが。
初めてご質問させていただきます。

この度、Djangoにてアプリを作成していたのですが、
一つのページを作る際に、MySQLにHTMLのタグごと保存し、
それを、必要に応じて呼び出しを行おうとしたところ、HTMLタグが有効に表示されず、
全てが、文字列として出力されてしまいました。
（HTMLタグとして機能せず、タグも表示される）

色々とgoogle先生に聞いてもこれといった答えが見出せず、悩み続けていました。

解決方法をご教授頂けますと助かります。

例）
MySQLに保存（モデル `models.TextField()` ）

```
<a href="http://hogehoge.com/" target="_blank">Hogehogeこっそり</a>
```

↓

DjangoからHTMLページに呼び出し

```
<a href="http://hogehoge.com/" target="_blank">Hogehogeこっそり</a>"
```

（タグが有効にならず、そのまま表示される）

おそらく、タグを含めて文字列として扱っているのだろうと思うのですが、
HTMLタグを有効にすることができません。

Answer (score 1):

HTML（テンプレート）側で呼び出すときに {{ data }} ではなく {{ data|safe }} とすればエスケープされずに表示されると思いますが、いかがでしょうか？

参考: [Django テンプレート言語](http://docs.djangoproject.jp/en/latest/topics/templates.html)